# Excel cell update date

Tags: excel

I am working with Excel 2016 spreadsheet with a few different worksheets in use. Manual data update is used with Copy-Paste method on one worksheet with other sheets running data analysis formulas.

Now given that data is unfortunately not live and several people are using this file, there is a question on how fresh the data is and should an update be done or not. Is there a formula that I could use to record when a particular cell was overwritten (corresponding to the date when data was refreshed)? IDEALLY without using VBA macros

Comment: I do not think it is possible to achieve cell level historical tracking in excel without VBA macros. If you are open to other solutions, sharepoint lists can be setup to achieve this kind of tracking of historical changes to individual elements in a 'row'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can get cell change information without macro. 
*But* you can use macro, which updates a particular column in sheet if Row (in the target range) has been changed.

For example:

```
'place in the target worksheet
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:B")) Is Nothing Then
     For Each cell In Target
       Call CellUpdate(sh, cell.Address, cell.Row, cell.Column)
     Next
  End If
End Sub

'place in a separate module
Sub CellUpdate(ByVal sheetName As String, ByVal cellName As String, ByVal cellRow As Long, cellColumn As Long)
    ' MsgBox (sheetName + " " + cellName+ " has been changed")
    Dim lastChanger As String
    lastChanger = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last author")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Cells(cellRow, 3).Value = "changed at " + Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + " by " + lastChanger          
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the whole data range and keep it in a very hidden sheet (a control sheet) called last active value as of ddMmmYY. And add another sheet called what changed since last active value as of ddMmmYY that compares each and every cell with the active sheet that everyone is using/refreshed vs the control sheet.